# How would I go about splitting a network with vlan using one network cable

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch, vlan

Please help me out with setting up a split home network. Here is my premise:

1. one external line (this would be the WAN cable connected to my ISP accessing the Internet)
2. one router (either the ISP's or my own; external line plugged in the WAN port)
3. a switch with VLAN management capabilities
4. link between the router and switch (obviously :) )
5. setting up the VLAN
   This step is meant to split my network in 2: one would be my "trusted" network (my laptop, phone etc.), the other would be "untrusted" (visitors, smart devices etc.)
6. the "output" cable (I'll explain shortly below)

So this is the premise, here are my requirements. As I said, I want to have 2 Intranets. VLAN0 would be the trusted one, VLAN1 would be the "untrusted" one. I have several rooms in my apartment and each room gets one Ethernet cable (hence the "one output cable" premise).

Obviously, in each room I would have both sets of devices, so for example a smart TV or a visitor (linking to the untrusted access point) and my own laptop/tablet/phone (linking to the trusted access point).

My problem (let's simplify and approach this for just one room):
Is there a way to use one eth cable, say in the living room, to link-up 2 access points? (one AP would have the untrusted SSID, the other would have the trusted SSID)

I was thinking the cable would would go into a HUB which would split into 2 AP/extenders/ small routers. The problem here I think is that since a single cable comes out of the switch and the switch has VLAN set up, then the interface that it comes out of (let's say VLAN0 - trusted) would prolly match the cable to THAT VLAN and would be unable to provide DHCP or other info to the other VLAN (VLAN1 - the untrusted one).

So basically my question is: is there a way to use one cable to "net up" 2 access points, each belonging to its own VLAN? And if so, how? (I haven't decided whether the router or the switch does DHCP - I was thinking the router but since I'm splitting the network between 2 Intranets, maybe the switch should do the logic?)

Another thing I thought of which might be easier (but more expensive) is to not use 2 vlans on the top level, use the single lines of each room and plug those into switches (which would then be split into VLANs). I am not sure how split they'll be this way though, as the idea was that say, if I had an AC in one room, one TV in another and the heating in the third room, they'd all see each other along with the hub, but be separate from the other devices (like my laptop or phone). Need confirmation here.

One more question: if the very top level would lead to a router (which leads to the Internet), does that also mean the Router would bridge the VLANs since it's a L3 device?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> setting up the VLAN This step is meant to split my network in 2: one would be my "trusted" network (my laptop, phone etc.), the other would be "untrusted" (visitors, smart devices etc.)

Although the latter two classes are "untrusted" from *your* point of view, they're also "untrusted" from *each other's* point of view. Should your visitors have unlimited access to your AC/heating/IoT devices? If not, then that makes at least 3 VLANs.

> So this is the premise, here are my requirements. As I said, I want to have 2 Intranets. VLAN0 would be the trusted one, VLAN1 would be the "untrusted" one. I have several rooms in my apartment and each room gets one Ethernet cable (hence the "one output cable" premise).

That's easy to do using 802.1Q tagging to separate multiple VLANs on the same cable. (Practically all switches "with VLAN capabilities" will support 802.1Q.) However, the devices on the receiving end need to understand the tags, so ideally you should have switches with 802.1Q VLAN support *in every room.*

Unmanaged, non-VLAN switches will only work somewhat – they'll put *all* devices in the same default VLAN (PVID). Only devices which can do 802.1Q tagging on their own will be able to make use of additional VLANs, but TVs won't, game consoles won't, printers won't, other IoT things also won't.

Also, do not use VLAN 0. In the 802.1Q tagging, zero is not allowed as the VLAN ID – the valid range is 1–4095, and the "default" VLAN is usually 1.

*(802.1Q tags with ID 0 are considered to not have any VLAN ID at all – such tags are used to specify just QoS packet priority.)*

> So basically my question is: is there a way to use one cable to "net up" 2 access points, each belonging to its own VLAN? And if so, how?

Yes, as long as *something* on both ends supports VLAN tagging (802.1Q tags). On the living-room side, it could be either a switch or a fancy AP.

So if you have a *second* switch with VLAN capabilities, then put that in the living room and connect each AP to an 'access' port with whatever VLAN it needs. The cable between rooms – between the two VLAN switches – is then connected to 'trunk' ports which carry multiple tagged VLANs at once.

If you only have an unmanaged non-VLAN switch, then it *may* be possible, but it completely depends on the firmware that the APs are running. The more you go towards "business grade" APs, the more likely that they'll support VLAN tagging for data. OpenWRT should be capable of this as well.

Most business/enterprise APs even support multiple SSIDs on different VLANs on the *same* AP. (Basically the same technology as "Guest SSID" on home routers, just more flexible in that you can choose which VLAN corresponds to which SSID.)

> (I haven't decided whether the router or the switch does DHCP - I was thinking the router but since I'm splitting the network between 2 Intranets, maybe the switch should do the logic?)

Many switches are really just L2 switches and don't deal with DHCP nor routing between VLANs. If you don't want to involve a separate router, then you need a "L3 switch" (i.e. a fancy L2 switch which also has L3 routing features).

But DHCP is less important than actually having a device which performs the routing between those VLANs and the Internet. (Technically, what matters isn't which device generates the DHCP responses, but which "gateway" IP address is specified in those responses, so it's fine if device A issues the DHCP leases but points towards device B for actual routing/gatewaying, or whatever.)

> One more question: if the very top level would lead to a router (which leads to the Internet), does that also mean the Router would bridge the VLANs since it's a L3 device?

Generally – no. (Bridging is a L2 operation.) The router is supposed to *route* between the VLANs.

However, in order for this to work using a single cable, the router must itself support VLAN tagging. (It will consider each VLAN to be a virtual Ethernet port, with its own IP addressing and everything.)

If the router doesn't support VLAN tagging, then it needs to be able to fully separate its LAN ports at L2. That is, if you have a common 4-port home router (the kind with a built-in LAN switch), it must be able to turn off the built-in switching between all its LAN ports, so that you could assign some ports to "LAN 1" and other ports to "LAN 2".

And if the router supports none of the above (i.e. it's strictly a single LAN device that has all its LAN ports permanently bridged)... then yes, best case it won't work at all, worst case it'll accidentally bridge all your VLANs together, and you won't be able to have two separate networks in the end.

> Another thing I thought of which might be easier (but more expensive) is to not use 2 vlans on the top level, use the single lines of each room and plug those into switches (which would then be split into VLANs).

That's not an alternative plan – that's something you *already* should do in order to properly use VLANs. If a room needs multiple VLANs, then it should have a switch with VLAN support.

> I am not sure how split they'll be this way though, as the idea was that say, if I had an AC in one room, one TV in another and the heating in the third room, they'd all see each other along with the hub, but be separate from the other devices (like my laptop or phone). Need confirmation here.

Well, that's right, but if you don't have those VLANs all the way to your router, then they will *also* be completely sealed off from Internet access. (Unless your switch also has L3 routing functions.)

Comment: Alright so it seems I understood (mostly by some logical guess work) most of the process from the get-go but lacked some vital info which you gave. I read about 802.1Q some time ago but completely forgot about it now. I'll do a re-read but I seem to remember it does the VLAN magic when packets are sent where they need to. So basically you're saying that for 2 eth rooms, I'd need the "top-level" VLAN switch, then another switch in the each room with VLAN support (for 802.1Q tags). This is what I initially guessed but lacked the info where it all fits together.

Comment: *The router is supposed to route between the VLANs* - my bad here, this is what I meant. The idea is to not to have them linked at all, just for them to have Inet acces. So from what I understand from you, most home routers will not be able to allocate separate ports which means it will keep them separate (which is what I want) but will be able to grant both VLANs (and machines linked) Inet access, correct? Regarding id0, it was an example, but thanks for that extra info. Knowledge is power :)

Comment: (argh I didn't know the Enter key adds a comment) So even if my TV or console won't know about 802.1Q my living room managed switch would and fix the puzzle. Right? OK, so let's say I did the setup: Internet acces router, VLAN main switch, room switches, VLAN1+2. Who does DHCP management? Can my router deal with it or should I use the VLAN-ing switch? I would assume the top level device is best for the job in most cases and each switch (and linked machine) will know how to reach the router and vice-versa. Right? So do I need a VLAN-managing router? Or will a basic one (say netgear, tplink) do?

Comment: You really _should_ use a router that is VLAN-capable. I have no idea whether any of the current netgear/tp-link/etc devices do, so cannot advise on that. (But they always seem to be limited in various arbitrary ways. People looking for cheap flexibility tend to use e.g. ER-X/ER-Lite, or Mikrotik routers, or OpenWRT-able devices.) Whether VLANs are allowed to access each other is defined by the firewall rules on the router that sits between them – it's up to you whether to allow everything or nothing or just certain things. For example, you could allow your phone to access the AC specifically.

Comment: OK I think I misunderstood this whole part it seems. So, I'll need room + top VLAN switch and also a VLAN router. Allowing access will be done via the router (this is fine). Since the ISP will most likely give me a dumb router, I'll prolly use that for the external WAN and buy my own for VLAN routing. What brands do you recommend for a VLAN management router? Also can you please confirm that a VLAN-able switch in the rooms will make up for APs or TVs without 1Q support? Thanks! Also in this scenario of a second level VLAN router and a top ISP dumb router with Inet access, who should do DHCP?

Comment: A switch that recognizes VLAN tags is enough -- devices connected to "access" ports will get just the filtered packets, with tags removed. (That's the main point of VLAN support in switches.) And in addition to TVs/APs/ToIoTs I would recommend having such a switch wherever Windows PCs are connected as well, because they sometimes react to tagged packets when they shouldn't. As for DHCP, you'll pretty much have a "two stacked routers" configuration -- the ISP router will serve DHCP for its own (outer) LAN, while your router will serve DHCP for the (V)LANs it manages.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the dumb router will just manage the VLAN router and the VLAN router will manage the whole intranet. That makes sense. For routers I found Cisco and Ubiquiti as nice recommendations. Some recommend Mikrotik  (but I am not sure I can find it here) and some say Linksys, but I think I'll stick to Cisco (or Ubiquiti if the Cisco price kills my wallet). Thank you for your patience and information. It was really useful and complete and seems to fit what I need.

Comment: Would using the same cable for multiple VLANs be a bottleneck? In the sense that you might share a 1Gb cable between multiple network devices.

Comment: It's exactly like sharing a cable between multiple devices. It can be a bottleneck if you have heavy traffic _between_ VLANs (e.g. the same packets go up to the router in one VLAN then back down in another VLAN, "router on a stick" style), but otherwise it isn't a problem in itself.

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, Ethernet networks need to associate one IP to one MAC so you need two of those.

I think WiFi is a better solution you might want to consider for your guest network. Most home routers have a feature called "Guest Network" built in that does exactly what you want. Then your entire network is just the trusted Ethernet & WiFi plus the WiFi guest network.

The other option not mentioned is that you could setup a virtual LAN using software. The simple way to do this is to use the virtual networking capabilities that comes with most virtual machine software. With these you are able to create virtual Ethernet cards.

Try https://www.vmware.com/ or https://www.virtualbox.org/ for examples of this software.

Also, you can tunnel between any networks using software. Look into SSH tunneling.

https://putty.org/
or
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ssh-tunnel/9nr7p38pklt4

None of these software solutions get past the fact that, at some point, if you have actual hardware on another network you need actual Ethernet ports for that hardware to physically attach to the gateway.

Comment: It feels like you are talking about a completely different kind of "virtual LAN" than OP's question? They mention having a "switch with VLAN management capabilities" which allows them to achieve precisely that (i.e. having two Ethernet networks on a single port and a single cable).

Comment: I am. I don't think the hardware solution will work without another network card. I was suggesting solutions that use software VLAN instead of the switch.

Comment: My problem is not another card, but another cable (or rather lack of it). I'd rather not go over software implementations and stick to hardware (tho it's more expensive, I feel I have more control over it).

Comment: This answer is good for those wanting to take the software approach. I'll go on using the hardware approach. I won't downvote you, but what user1686 recommended is what I needed. Still, thanks for offering an alternative, as I didn't think of this as a last resort.

Comment: I don't recommend using putty.org, as it is not supported/encouraged by PuTTY's developers, as you can see from the [Latest Official PuTTY documentation's section about putty.org](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.77/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-putty-org) (e.g. [Version 0.77 of that documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-putty-org)) is not referring to that domain positively.  More commended: Download PuTTY-related software from [the proper website](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).